# I encountered a problem while following a tutorial on building an app with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

The error that appears is as follows "Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String is expected". How can I solve this problem?

The source code is as follows:

```
package com.example.submission2.Activity
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.drawable.DrawableTransitionOptions
import com.example.submission2.Adapter.AdapterSectionPager
import com.example.submission2.ViewModel.DetailVM
import com.example.submission2.databinding.ActivityDetailBinding






class DetailActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object{
        const val EXTRA_USERNAME = "extra_username"
    }

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityDetailBinding
    private lateinit var viewModel: DetailVM



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityDetailBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        supportActionBar?.apply {
            setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
            setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
        }
        val username = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_USERNAME)

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory()).get(DetailVM::class.java)

        viewModel.setPenggunaDetail(username)
        viewModel.getPenggunaDetail().observe(this) {
            if (it != null) {
                binding.apply {
                    tvNamaDetail.text = it.name
                    tvUsernameDetail.text = it.login
                    tvCompanyDetail.text = it.company
                    tvEmailDetail.text = it.email
                    tvFollowersDetail.text = "${it.followers} Followers"
                    tvFollowingDetail.text = "${it.following} Follwing"
                    Glide.with(this@DetailActivity)
                        .load(it.avatar_url)
                        .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
                        .centerCrop()
                        .into(ivDetailProfil)


                }
            }
        }
        val sectionPagerAdpter = AdapterSectionPager(this,supportFragmentManager)
        binding.apply {
            viewPager.adapter = sectionPagerAdpter
            tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
        }
    }
}
```

error appears on the line "viewModel.set User Data(username)" username is used in extra_username which will be called in main

```
for main activity as follows:
package com.example.submission2.Activity

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.KeyEvent
import android.view.View
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.submission2.Adapter.AdapterPengguna
import com.example.submission2.DataBase.Pengguna
import com.example.submission2.R
import com.example.submission2.ViewModel.MainVM
import com.example.submission2.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var viewModel: MainVM
    private lateinit var adapter: AdapterPengguna

    private fun searchPengguna(){
        binding.apply {
            val query = etSearch.text.toString()
            if (query.isEmpty())return
            showLoading(true)
            viewModel.setSearchPengguna(query)
        }
    }

    private fun showLoading(state: Boolean){
        if (state){
            binding.progressBarMain.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }else{
            binding.progressBarMain.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        adapter = AdapterPengguna()
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        adapter.setOnItemClickCallback(object :AdapterPengguna.OnItemClickCallback{
            override fun onItemCliked(data: Pengguna) {
                Intent(this@MainActivity,DetailActivity::class.java).also {
                    it.putExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA_USERNAME, data.login)
                    startActivity(it)
                }
            }

        })

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this,ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory()).get(MainVM::class.java)

        binding.apply {
            rvPengguna.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
            rvPengguna.setHasFixedSize(true)
            rvPengguna.adapter = adapter

            btnSearch.setOnClickListener {
                searchPengguna()
            }

            etSearch.setOnKeyListener { v, keyCode, event ->
                if (event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
                    searchPengguna()
                    return@setOnKeyListener true
                }
                return@setOnKeyListener false
            }
        }
        viewModel.getSearchPengguna().observe(this,{
            if (it!= null){
                adapter.setList(it)
                showLoading(false

                )
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code there is no such line as `viewModel.setUserData`

I guess that the error occurs in the line `viewModel.setPenggunaDetail(username)`

In this case, you should pay attention to the fact that the all `intent.getExtra` calls returns nullable values.

Thus, if the `setPenggunaDetail` call expects a non-nullable argument, you must first check *username* value for null